# SQL function - returing a value from a table and changing its type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create an SQL function using Postgres that does the following:
For a value in the id column of testtable, return the corresponding yval, but as text rather than an integer:

```
createdb testdb
psql testdb

create table testtable (id int, yval int);

INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(632, 25);
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(280, 99);
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(532, 17);
INSERT INTO testtable VALUES(108, 59);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
func1(int) returns int
AS $$
SELECT yval
FROM testtable
WHERE id = $1
$$ language sql;

select * from func1(632);
```

The final line returns a value of 25 (an integer). How can I modify the function to return '25' (text), without altering testtable?

Comment: You don't need a function, you can do that in the query itself  for very cheap `SELECT yval::text FROM testtable WHERE id = ?`

Comment: True, but this is just the part of the function where I was stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast your value in select and assign the proper data type in function delcaration

eg: for text

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    func1(int) returns text
    AS $$
    SELECT yval::text
    FROM testtable
    WHERE id = $1
    $$ language sql;
```